# I need to to copy one file content into a new file by doing some manipulation in perl

Tags: string, perl

I have a pipe-delimited file named `old.txt` that looks like this:

```
Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4|Data5 
Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4|Data5
Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4|Data5
```

I need to copy its contents to a new file, named `new.txt`, but with the second column removed:

```
Data1|Data3|Data4|Data5
Data1|Data3|Data4|Data5
Data1|Data3|Data4|Data5
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I love Perl as much as the next guy, but why not just write `cut -d'|' -f1,3-5 < old.txt > new.txt`?

Comment: well the above mentioned part is small task that i need to do in the perl script which I have already developed for file comparison but I need to remove a field for the comparison to happen ... will this cut command will work inside a perl script

Comment: It sounds like you're going about this the wrong way; if you're trying to compare files inside Perl, then you shouldn't be needing to save temporary modified versions to disk. You should be able to handle all of this inside Perl-space. But to answer your question: yes, you can invoke Bash from Perl, by writing `system 'bash', '-c', 'cut -d"|" -f1,3-5 < old.txt > new.txt'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use autodie;

open my $old_fh, "<", "old.txt";
open my $new_fh, ">", "new.txt";

while(my $line = <$old_fh>) {
    # @data should have a more meaningful name
    my @data = split /\|/, $line; 

    # remove the second element in the array. 
    splice @data, 1, 1;
    print $new_fh join ' | ', @data;
}

close $old_fh;
close $new_fh;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is trivial when using [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV). Here's a sample script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        binary   => 1,
        eol      => $/,
        sep_char => "|",
    });
open my $in, "<", "old.txt" or die $!;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($in)) {
    splice @$row, 1, 1;                 # remove 2nd column
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, $row);         # print the rest
}
```

**Output:**

```
Data1|Data3|Data4|Data5
Data1|Data3|Data4|Data5
Data1|Data3|Data4|Data5
```